# macro to set formatting of cells

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to make a macro to format cells of a table automatically. (in **Word 2013**)

Recording desired action as a macro results this code:

```
    With Selection.Cells(1)
        .TopPadding = CentimetersToPoints(0)
        .BottomPadding = CentimetersToPoints(0)
        .LeftPadding = CentimetersToPoints(0.19)
        .RightPadding = CentimetersToPoints(0.19)
        .WordWrap = True
        .FitText = False
    End With
```

Running it again applies changes only to the first cell (not surprising after looking the code).

I've tried writing appropriate loop around it:

```
For Each c in Selection.Cells
    ....
Next c
```

But its performance is very slow, even if I switch of `Screenupdating`.

Is there a better way for doing it with a macro?

Comment: About how slow are we talking?

Comment: In a medium document (150 - 200 pages) for a table of 200 cells it takes cc 20-40 seconds, doing the same manually is done immediately.

Comment: Are you only modifying some of the cells in the table? If most of the cells need to have the same padding, would it make sense to alter the the cell padding values for the whole table (via Selection.Tables(1).TopPadding etc. ) then re-pad individual cells that need it, and apply wordwrap/fittext to all cells? Here, that last process seemed to be relatively fast, but perhaps my test data is too simple. Otherwise, the only speed improvement I could make was significant, but not massive, achieved by copying the whole table to a new document, modifying the layout there, then copying back.

Comment: It depends on which properties you're actually interested in. The cell padding can be set for the entire table. WordWrap and FitText apparently applies only to `Cell` objects and can't be applied to the entire table or a selection of cells through the object model. I suspect the reason for the slowness is Word having to recalculate the page layout for each change... You might try switching to NormalView before executing the code and setting `Options.Pagination=false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wasn't able to select all the cells in VBA, the workaround is to create a temporary document to where I copy the table, format there and copy it back.

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub NimitTest02()
  Dim oTbl As Table
  Dim oCell As Cell
  Dim i As Integer
  Set oTbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns.Count
  For Each oRow In oTbl.Rows
    Set oCell = oRow.Cells(i)
        oCell.Select
    With Selection.Cells(1)
        .TopPadding = CentimetersToPoints(0)
        .BottomPadding = CentimetersToPoints(0)
        .LeftPadding = CentimetersToPoints(0.19)
        .RightPadding = CentimetersToPoints(0.19)
        .WordWrap = True
       .FitText = False
    End With
  Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It worths a little explanation

Comment: It's just the same code what I already posted in the question. " loop around it ... But its performance is very slow, even if I switch of Screenupdating."